# JSF please don't escape my html

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf, xss

From the dbms I get stuff like `<font color="red"> abc</font>`. When it reaches the `${someManagedBean.someValue}` in my xhtml file the output is sanitized. That is great for 99,999% of all cases.

Question: Is there some way to disable this auto escaping?

Bonus Question: Can I only allow html and disallow javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/outputText.html

`escape=false`

Not sure about preventing JS only though. You might have to parse the HTML yourself to get rid of `<script>` and contents.

---

**EDIT** - Removed link (http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html) because it was stale. Replaced with Oracle link.

Comment: If you want to allow html, but disallow javascriot, look at OWASP antisamy

Answer (score 14):

```
<h:outputText value="#{someManagedBean.someValue}" escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

outputFormat tag can help you.
Please check http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-outputformat-example/