# Saving froala editor content to pdf in jsp/servlets

Tags: servlets, pdf, itext, froala

I have embeded froala editor in my jsp and want to save all the content typed in the editor with all the formatting and images as PDF file . 
I currently have embeded the editor and pass the content using the form submit button.
On submitting the parameters to servlet that uses a itext libraries , i created the pdf but the formatted text is not displayed as formatted in the pdf file.
Instead the formatted text printed in pdf with html tags like

around them. 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should mark the HTML as safe to display. This has been answered in another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442668/1806855

Comment: Buddy, i didnt get 'mark the html as safe to display' ?

Comment: By default the html tags are displayed as text instead of html. You should tell JSP to display it as safe html. I am not familiar to JSP to tell you exactly what you should do, but this is the main idea.