# Disable HTML-escaping in entire template of <ui:composition template>

Tags: jsf, templates, jsf-2, escaping, facelets

We read in a [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442584/jsf-please-dont-escape-my-html), that we could tell JSF engine not to escape the values of an element:

```
<h:outputText value="#{messages.text}" style="font-weight:bold" escape="false" />
```

But how should I prevent escape on the whole template. My page reads a template from a http-url, which has contents that are semi-dynamic. That semi-dynamic template has mime-escaped encoded chars in it.

```
<ui:composition template="#{template.url}" ...
```

I tried doing

```
<ui:composition template="#{template.url}" escape="false"
```

But it does not work. Perhaps because, ui:composition does not take an *escape* attribute.

How do I prevent escape-effect on the whole template?

Comment: AFAIK you can not do this.  However if you want to retrieve dynamic content you can output it directly in the template with something like `<h:outputText value="#{templateB.content}" escape="false"/>`.

Comment: where do you load the template from? Do you use a `ResourceResolver`?

Comment: The template is a web page, served by an apache httpd.

Comment: Pls read up on this, if you don't know what a template url is: http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-composition.html

Comment: I don't get it: 1. MIME escaping is not HTML escaping - MIME escaped characters should need no special HTML escaping. 2. I can't find the term "template url" or even "url" on the given page. But what it states, and what the specification says: The template has to be a valid facelets file, not just a HTML page. 3. _But it does not work_ is a very unspecific description.