# Internationalization message with HTML tags

Tags: jsf, internationalization, el, facelets, resourcebundle

I have the following message in my resource bundle properties file:

```
    message1=This is a <strong>message</strong>
```

And in my facelets page I have:

```
    <p>#{bundle.message1}</p>
```

However when the message is displayed it shows the tags as text so I see

```
    "<strong>message</strong>"
```

instead of "message" in bold.

What do I have to do to see it in bold?

Comment: use an h:outputText and set 'escape' to false' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442584/jsf-please-dont-escape-my-html

Comment: The title of this question is wrong in several ways. First, no need to add 'jsf' to it, since it is already tagged that way. Secondly, 'i18n' is nowhere in your question. It is plain about the escaping of html. It is even not resource bundle related (try with returning the strings from a plain getter). So when you 'analyze' your problem like I just did, you'd easily find the duplicate.